# jQuery class selector not working after .NET 5 upgrade

Tags: jquery, asp.net5

I am working on a .NET5 upgrade and while upgrading the code I found that my jQuery selector for classes are not working. It is a MVC project with razor pages.

In my view I have my script at the top and I call the menus items with anchor tags:

```
<script src="~/menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a href="#" class="menu-pop create_new_project" data-position="right" data-content="New Project" id="new-project">
   <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
   <span>New Project</span>
</a>
```

then in my menu.js it is called like this:

```
$('.create_new_project').on('click', function (e) { ...do stuff});
```

**Update**
Just found that if I redirect, to another page, it triggers. I can confirm that the scripts is present when you view the menu. There are also no errors in the developer console. I am really not sure what I am doing wrong.

I tried to use the id instead of the class and adding selectors:

```
$('#new-project').on('click', function (e) { ...do stuff});
$('#new-project').on('click', 'a', function (e) { ...do stuff});
```

The issue still persisted.

It is loaded in the DOM
[image]

Comment: Is the `.create_new_project` element available in the DOM when the page loads, or is it dynamically created?

Comment: It is there, I will add an image. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Note that the image from the DOM inspector shows that the element exists, but not that it existed when the page first loaded. It's an important distinction when working with event handlers. As a test, try this instead: `$(document).on('click', '.create_new_project', function (e) { ...do stuff});`

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan I will try that

Comment: Just before you're `.on` line add: `console.log($(selector).length)` change "selector" to your selector, eg "#new-project" - if it's zero (0) then your event has nothing to attach to *at that time* (hence add it directly before the event line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead this.
`$('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() { // do something });`

here any (including dynamic) element will be triggered.

this link might be help full. => [How do I attach events to dynamic HTML elements with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks @MMJ that did the trick